# Python class instance returns a reference instead of the value

Tags: python, flask

I am a novice in web development using flask and encountered this bug. The flask program runs quite well until I pass the values to the Movie1 object in the request.py file. It is an instance of the Movie class in the movie.py file. I have ran tests to show that all code before that is running without a bug. SO when the program runs, I get the reference of the data instead of the actual data(which is what i want). I'd really appreciate some help here.

request.py

```
from app import app
import urllib.request, json
from .models import movie

Movie1 = movie.Movie

#Getting API key
api_key = app.config['MOVIE_API_KEY']

#Getting the movie base URL
base_url = app.config['MOVIE_API_BASE_URL']

movie_results = []
def get_movies(category):
    '''
    Function that gets the json response to our url request
    '''
    get_movies_url = base_url.format(category, api_key)



    with urllib.request.urlopen(get_movies_url) as url:
        get_movies_data = url.read()
        get_movies_response = json.loads(get_movies_data)

        #movie_results = None

        if get_movies_response['results']:
            movie_results_list = get_movies_response['results']
            movie_results = process_results(movie_results_list)

    return movie_results

def process_results(movie_list):
    '''
    Function  that processes the movie result and transform them to a list of Objects

    Args:
    movie_list: A list of dictionaries that contain movie details

    Returns :
    movie_results: A list of movie objects
    '''
    #movie_results = []
    for movie_item in movie_list:
        id1 = movie_item.get('id')
        title1 = movie_item.get('original_title')
        overview1 = movie_item.get('overview')
        poster1 = movie_item.get('poster_path')
        vote_average1 = movie_item.get('vote_average')
        vote_count1 = movie_item.get('vote_count')

        if poster1:
            movie_object = Movie1(id1, title1, overview1, poster1, vote_average1, vote_count1)
            movie_results.append(movie_object)



    return movie_results
```

movie.py

```
class Movie:
    '''
    Movie class to define Movie Objects
    '''
    def __init__(self, id, title, overview, poster, vote_average, vote_count):

        '''
        Args:
        1. Title - The name of the movie
        2. Overview - A short description on the movie
        3. image- The poster image for the movie
        4. vote_average - Average rating of the movie
        5. vote_count - How many people have rated the movie
        6. id - The movie id
        '''
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.overview = overview
        self.poster = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/'+ poster
        self.vote_average = vote_average
        self.vote_count = vote_count
```

output:

....

Comment: Python does not support pass-by-value. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a quick guide to how Python objects, variables, and parameter passing work.

Comment: Your code is too long so I didn't read it yet. Just let you know, if you return a `dict`, `list`, `tuple`, or instance of a custom class, and you want to get items inside these types, it is passed by reference. if you return a `float`, `int`, `string`, and you want to get the value itself, it is passed by value.

Comment: @YangHG: Not true. Python objects are passed the same way regardless of their type, and neither pass by reference nor pass by value correctly describes how they are passed.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Uh you are right, if we read the CPython implement, we can find all of python objects are passed by the same way.

Comment: thanks all for the feedback. im hoping on knowing how ill be able to get the values instead

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks a lot  for the link. I've learnt quite some info. Unfortunately, I havent really grasped a solution to my problem. Or should I simlpy do away with the class object?